Playwright - page.goto() throwing error continuously in AWS Lambda
Lambda 1:
playwright-aws-lambda v0.9.0
Node 16
Lambda 2:
playwright-aws-lambda v0.10.0
Node 18
AWS Lambda
CI/CD Gitlab
When trying to go to a URL with page.goto(), getting continuous error - 'Error: page.goto: Target page, context or browser has been closed'.
At handler level the error says - "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')\n at d. (/var/task/src/handler.js:1:17387)\n at Generator.next ()\n at a (/var/task/src/handler.js:1:15631)"
The above error in occurring in lambdas which got built by Gitlab pipeline on/after April 18. The same code is still working fine for the lambdas that were build and deployed before April 18.
The deployment packages for old and new deployments are totally same - node module versions and configs.
Any recent updates somewhere would have affected this? TIA.

Is your code literally just a puppeteer.launch(), a browser.newPage() and a page.goto()? Even if it's just that simple, I'd share it so it's clear that it's not your code's fault. Usually the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close') happens when the launch throws and browser isn't defined, meaning .close() can't be called on undefined. Error: page.goto: Target page, context or browser has been closed usually means the browser launched successfully, though. Anyway, I'd say this needs an [mcve]. Thanks.

@ggorlen Thanks for the answer. Seems the issue was with AWS runtime.
The runtime version (Node.js 18.x, x86_64) was automatically updated from
"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:0cdcfbdefbc5e7d3343f73c2e2dd3cba17d61dea0686b404502a0c9ce83931b9"
to
"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:b475b23763329123d9e6f79f51886d0e1054f727f5b90ec945fcb2a3ec09afdd"
Switching to manual and using the former fixed it.

Great--feel free to post a self answer so the question shows as resolved.

The problem was with AWS runtime. The runtime version (Node.js 18.x, x86_64) was automatically updated from arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:0cdcfbdefbc5e7d3343f73c2e2dd3cba17d61dea0686b404502a0c9ce83931b9 to arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:b475b23763329123d9e6f79f51886d0e1054f727f5b90ec945fcb2a3ec09afdd
Switching to manual and using the former fixed it.
But we still need a solid solution for this to work with newer versions of Node as well.
